# getting strange error when submitting to iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I am on the last stage of my upload, and i clicked submit, only to receive the error;

There was an error saving changes: NullPropertyException. Stack is: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@5528cffb

what does that mean?
I am 99% sure I built correctly.
the error changes ( the @  bit) after a refresh and click of submit again.

Help me out please!

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's websites all run on WebObjects, which is Java based. Hence the Java error. This is almost certainly a problem on their side. I'd try submitting again tomorrow and if it still fails, contacting their support.